# What does Lightmap Pack's "Pack Quality" option do?

Tags: uv

What does the "Pack Quality" option do in the Lightmap Pack settings box? The option's tooltip says *Pre Packing before the complex boxpack*.

[image: Lightmap Pack options]

Answer (score 11):

Packing quality controls how efficiently laid out the UV islands are on the texture.

A low pack quality means there is more texture space wasted (but faster unwrap), a higher value means the UV islands are better optimized to use the entire texture, at the expense of unwrapping time.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be very quick regardless of quality. Why don't they just hardcode it at 48? Is there anything else it affects, such as stretch?

Comment: The speed differences will only show up when you are unwrapping models that have a lot more geometry than you see in the example Mike shows.  Basic scenes usually process quickly no matter how slow the algorithm.